# UIImagePickerController give black screen in accessing PhotoLibrary

Tags: screen, uiimagepickercontroller, swift2, photolibrary

I am just accessing the PhotoLibrary not even the camera. It gives a black screen like [this](http://www.screencast.com/t/SHP1eUrnk1f).

Here is the code:

```
@IBAction func selectProfileImageBtnTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    
    let myImagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    
    myImagePicker.allowsEditing = false
    myImagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
    
    presentViewController(myImagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    
}
```

How to solve this?